# How to loop object data into the table?

Tags: angular5

I have following object with columns and data. I want to display the columns value using *ngFor.

SO far I have tried following code:

```
public productLists;

this.productLists = [];
this.productLists = this.loadProductLists();
```

### html

```
<tr *ngFor="let column of productLists.columns">
                    <th scope="col">{{column}}</th>
                </tr>
```

### data

```
columns:
action: "Action"
product_code_clip: "Product Code Clip"
product_name_clip: "Product Name Clip"
year: "Year"
__proto__: Object
data: (15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Comment: does this.loadProductLists(); is an async operation?. Promise, or Observable?. If it so, append **async** to ngFor `<tr *ngFor="let column of productLists.columns | async">`

Comment: <div *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(product list.columns)"> I try this for now ? Using async and this is same??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to iterate the data array within your columns object?

```
<tr *ngFor="let column of productLists.columns.data">
                    <th scope="col">{{column}}</th>
                </tr>
```